# Make cards and images the same size - how can I do it with CSS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css, material-ui

I'm using `react`. `Material-ui` is for `Cards`. For `Grid` I'm using CSS Grid Layout. So far it looks like this:

[image]

But my goal is something like this:

[image]

And I have 2 problems:

1. I want to have all these `cards` the same height (415px). I tried  height: 415px on `.BeerListingScroll-info-box` but it doesn't work.
2. Images of bottles and kegs are diffrent in size [keg (80px x 160px) vs. bottle (80px x 317px)]. Is there any way to make them more similar in rendered size?

-

Code:

`BeerListingScroll`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReduxLazyScroll from 'redux-lazy-scroll';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { fetchBeers } from '../../actions/';

import BeersListItem from '../../components/BeersListItem';
import ProgressIndicator from '../../components/ProgressIndicator';

import './style.css';

class BeerListingScroll extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.loadBeers = this.loadBeers.bind(this);
  }

  loadBeers() {
    const { skip, limit } = this.props.beers;
    this.props.fetchBeers(skip, limit);
  }

  render() {
    const { beersArray, isFetching, errorMessage, hasMore } = this.props.beers;
    return (
      <div className="container beers-lazy-scroll">
        <ReduxLazyScroll
          isFetching={isFetching}
          errorMessage={errorMessage}
          loadMore={this.loadBeers}
          hasMore={hasMore}
        >
          <div className="BeerListingScroll-wrapper">
            {beersArray.map(beer => (
              <div key={beer.id} className="BeerListingScroll-info-box">
                <BeersListItem beer={beer} />
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </ReduxLazyScroll>
        <div className="row beers-lazy-scroll__messages">
          {isFetching && (
            <div className="alert alert-info">
              <ProgressIndicator />
            </div>
          )}

          {!hasMore &&
            !errorMessage && (
              <div className="alert alert-success">
                All the beers has been loaded successfully.
              </div>
            )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    beers: state.beers,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ fetchBeers }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BeerListingScroll);
```

`BeerListingScroll css`

```
.BeerListingScroll-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  margin: 0;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(320px, 1fr) ) ;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.BeerListingScroll-info-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
  width: 320px;
}


/* This applies from 600px onwards */
@media (min-width: 1820px) {
  .BeerListingScroll-wrapper {
    margin: 0 400px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1620px) {
  .BeerListingScroll-wrapper {
    margin: 0 300px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1366px) {
  .BeerListingScroll-wrapper {
    margin: 0 200px;
  }
}
```

`BeerListItem` is the child of BeerListingScroll

```
import React from 'react';
import Card, { CardContent } from 'material-ui/Card';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';

function BeerListItem(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Card raised>
        <CardContent>
          <img src={props.beer.image_url} alt="beer" width="30%" />
          <Typography variant="headline" component="h2">
            {props.beer.name}
          </Typography>
          <Typography component="p">{props.beer.tagline}</Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}

export default BeerListItem;
```

Full project on github -> [Github](https://github.com/elminsterrr/beer-app-q2)

Comment: this may just be a HTML + CSS questions -- could you also include the rendered HTML code as it is generated on the web page?

Comment: But really -- find the element that is the white background and set the height of the div to that -- if it won't adjust use the web developer tool bar to see if there are any styles overwriting your intent

Comment: use flexbox - ideal for equal height rows.  but as you haven't create an [mcve], I'm voting to close

Comment: You are encountering an artwork problem! Anytime you change the aspect ratios to make images scale, you come across the problem of distorting the images, for a truly professional look you refactor the artwork, so the images are uniform.

Comment: Your best bet is to use CSS `background`. It offers the `cover` and some other nice, easy functionality. See MDN's [Scaling background images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Scaling_background_images)

Answer (score 6):

So for image sizes here I got great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49325210/how-to-make-two-different-images-similar-in-size-without-distortion/49325270#49325270).

And I added:

```
.BeerListItem-img {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 250px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 250px;
}
```

And for card size I just added inside `BeerListItem` class to `Card` like so (`.BeerListItem-main-card`):

```
function BeerListItem(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Card raised className="BeerListItem-main-card">
        <CardContent>
          <img
            src={props.beer.image_url}
            alt="beer"
            className="BeerListItem-img"
          />
          <Typography variant="headline" component="h2">
            {props.beer.name}
          </Typography>
          <Typography component="p">{props.beer.tagline}</Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here is corresponding css to that component.

```
.BeerListItem-main-card {
  width: 320px;
  height: 415px;
}

.BeerListItem-img {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 250px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 250px;
}
```

With that two changes, I've managed to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1):

You should try exploring display:flex;

Here is a link to a fantastic code pen that may help you achieve what you want:

https://codepen.io/enxaneta/full/adLPwv

More specifically here is an example I've created with what you might be trying to achieve.

https://jsfiddle.net/dalecarslaw/sxdr3eep/

Here is the areas of code you should focus on:

```
  display:flex;
  align-items:space-between;
  justify-content:space-between;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
```

Answer (score 1):

by using display flex,  my humble suggestion is  adding "flex:1" to parent element of the card. This will allow your display to set the same size to each children and with that auto adjust each card to the same size, including the img.

I solved that, using that property.