# How to make two different images similar in size without distortion?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm loading 250 elements from the database and I need to render `img` for each one of them.

Unfortunately `imgs` are coming in two different sizes:

1. keg 381x760 (px)
2. bottle 272x1058 (px)

I can't hardcode it because I don't know in what order these image element will be coming from the server.

Here is my `Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example`

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.img {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h2>HTML Image</h2>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img class="img" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dfe57evk4/image/upload/v1521215919/2_paabuv.png" alt="Mountain View">
    <img class="img" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dfe57evk4/image/upload/v1521215916/keg_quozwj.png" alt="Mountain View">

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

How can I make them similar in size without image distortion?

Here is desired effect:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use max values for height and width and use auto for both too in order to re scale properly:

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.img {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 250px;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h2>HTML Image</h2>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img class="img" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dfe57evk4/image/upload/v1521215919/2_paabuv.png" alt="Mountain View">
    <img class="img" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dfe57evk4/image/upload/v1521215916/keg_quozwj.png" alt="Mountain View">

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

You can use responsive measurements if you need to (vh - vw or vmin - vmax).

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much! I will accept as soon as I can!